# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

```
/* Create trigger for Message system*/
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS TRG_MSG
AFTER INSERT ON Order_Detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Messages (Order_ID, Member_ID, Message, Msg_Date)
    VALUES (new.Order_ID, new.Member_ID, 'Your Order is Placed!...', CURRENT_DATE);
END;
```

In MySQL, I am getting this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DELIMITER

Like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS TRG_MSG
AFTER INSERT ON Order_Detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Messages (Order_ID, Member_ID, Message, Msg_Date)
    VALUES (NEW.Order_ID, NEW.Member_ID, 'Your Order is Placed!...', CURRENT_DATE);
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [`CREATE TRIGGER` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) does not support the `IF NOT EXISTS` option.

Also, you need to redefine the `DELIMITER` before you create the trigger, so the embedded `;`s in the body of the trigger do not clash with the surrounding `create trigger` statement.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER RG_MSG
AFTER INSERT ON Order_Detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Messages (Order_ID, Member_ID, Message, Msg_Date)
    VALUES (new.Order_ID, new.Member_ID, 'Your Order is Placed!...', CURRENT_DATE);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMMW2oJ9HtRtaAGK3pYgbk/1)**.